# DoctrineFixturesBundle: Fatal Error in LoadRubricaData::load()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't launch my simple Fixture, I installed the bundle in the right way and put the 2 lines in autoload.php and Appkernel.php like stated at [here](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html), and then I created my fixture class as it follows:

```
<?php

namespace ABCBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use ABCBundle\Entity\Rubrica;

class LoadRubricaData implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $rubrica = new Rubrica();
        $rubrica->setX("XXX");
        $manager->persist($rubrica);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
?>
```

But when I try to launch it from the CLI with

> php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load

I get:

> Fatal error: Declaration of ABCBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadRubricaData::load() must be compatible with that of Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface::load() in [...]ABCBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadRubricaData.php on line 10

but if you go to take a look at that interface you can see it's correct:

```
interface FixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager
     */
    function load(ObjectManager $manager);
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damnit, I forgot to add the line

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
```